# Query with multiple subqueries required in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for some query help

here is the following table data

```
Name    Runs    Status
Ram         50  out
Ram         103 not out
Krish   51  out
Sam         15  out
Ram         15  out
Krish   78  not out
```

I am expecting a single query to give the folllowing results

```
Name    Total   >100    >50&<100    TotalTimes  Notout 
Ram        168  1           1         3          1
Sam        15   0           0         1          0
Krish      129  0           2         2          1
```

I am able to write the query to get the total, Totaltimes with the help of Group By functionalities, I am stuck with the rest

Here is the query I have come up

```
select Name, sum(Runs) as total, count(*) as totalTimes
from tempTable 
where classID IN (Select classID from upcoming_Clases where classes_id=175) 
group by Name order by total desc
```

I am using the Mysql Database

Comment: I suspect you actually meant for your third output column to be `>=100`; otherwise batsmen with exactly a century will not be counted in either the half-century or century columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using case:

```
select Name, 
       sum(Runs) as total, 
       count(case when Runs>100 then 1 end) `>100`,
       count(case when Runs>50 and Runs<100 then 1 end) `>50&<100`,
       count(*) as totalTimes,
       count(case when Status='not out' then 1 end) `Not Out`
from tempTable 
where classID IN (Select classID from upcoming_Clases where classes_id=175) 
group by Name order by total desc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) together with [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to test your criteria:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(Runs) AS Total,
    SUM(IF(Runs>100, 1, 0)) AS `>100`,
    SUM(IF(Runs>50 AND Runs<100), 1, 0) AS `>50&<100`,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalTimes,
    SUM(IF(Status='not out', 1, 0)) AS Notout
FROM tempTable
WHERE classID IN (SELECT classID FROM upcoming_Clases WHERE classes_id = 175)
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: The use of JOIN instead of IN assumes that there will only be one record for each classID on upcoming_Clases.

Comment: Because if there was more than one record on upcoming_Clases for a given classID, it would multiply the SUM and COUNT values accordingly.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Agreed.  Rather than delete my answer, I'll leave `SUM(IF(..))` as an alternative to `COUNT(CASE ...))` - whilst I think yours is more clear (hence gave +1), this form could be instructive for other queries the OP/others might want to perform.

Comment: I thought they were both valid answers, so I upvoted yours after the JOIN was changed to an IN. I agree that the `SUM(IF(` is a useful technique.